# Duplicate values returning from mySQL JOIN Statement. Help?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am having a hard time creating a mySQL join statement.

The issue is that it seems to return the correct results, but it returns duplicates.

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT Photos.Filename, Photos.Filetype
FROM Photos, PhotoUserTags
WHERE PhotoUserTags.User_ID IN ($friendlist) && PhotoUserTags.Photo_ID = Photos.Photo_ID && Photos.Event_ID = $eid");
```

I am new to these statements, any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one, the logical and in mysql is not `&&` but `AND`, like this:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE field1 = 'value1' AND field2 = 'value2';
```

You should also use the newer join syntax like this:

```
SELECT Photos.Filename, Photos.Filetype
FROM Photos, PhotoUserTags
INNER JOIN PhotoUserTags ON PhotoUserTags.Photo_ID = Photos.Photo_ID
WHERE PhotoUserTags.User_ID IN ($friendlist)
  AND Photos.Event_ID = $eid
GROUP BY Photos.Photo_ID
```

Note the join expression (I used inner join, assuming a matching record needs to exist in both tables) - it makes your where cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

Here's your query:

```
SELECT 
  Photos.Filename, Photos.Filetype
FROM Photos
INNER JOIN PhotoUserTags ON (PhotoUserTags.Photo_ID = Photos.Photo_ID)
WHERE 
  Photos.Event_ID = $eid
  AND PhotoUserTags.User_ID IN ($friendlist) /* assuming they are IDs separated by a comma) */
GROUP BY Photos.Photo_ID;
```

I would also `explain` this query just in case you use the right indexes to maximize the performance of your query

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT Photos.Filename, Photos.Filetype
FROM Photos, PhotoUserTags
WHERE PhotoUserTags.User_ID IN ($friendlist) && PhotoUserTags.Photo_ID = Photos.Photo_ID && Photos.Event_ID = $eid  GROUP BY Photos.Photo_ID");
```